# How to write to a file multiple times

Tags: c#, io

I want to write a debug log file for my app.

I don't want to use NuGet because I have a `log4net` installation and it has caused problems.

I want to write a simple .log file so that I can add content through the process

I need something like:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + ".log", "<some text>,");

 // some lines of code here

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + ".log", "<more text>");
```

When I will open the log file I want to see: `<some text>,<more text>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to *append* (not *rewrite*) then put `Append` instead of `Write`:

```
 ...

 System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path + ".log", "<more text>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to simply append? If so, you can simply use:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + ".log", "<some text>,");

 // some lines of code here

System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path + ".log", "<more text>");
```